# Get item name from DialogIinterface click event

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

```
List<String> fetchcategorynames=obj_Categorydb.fetchcategory();
CharSequence[] categorynames=fetchcategorynames.toArray(new CharSequence[fetchcategorynames.size()]);
Log.i(TAG,"Charsequence:"+categorynames.toString());                                
AlertDialog.Builder alert_Categoryitem=new AlertDialog.Builder(WorkActivity.this,R.style.cust_dialog);
alert_Categoryitem.setTitle("Category Names");                                
alert_Categoryitem.setItems(categorynames,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        //how to get the item name
    }
});
alert_Categoryitem.show();
```

Comment: Would you like to maybe add a question in addition to the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
alert_Categoryitem.setItems(categorynames,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        String result = categorynames[which];
    }
});
```

Just use `which` as a selected index.